# "it yields accurate predictions for Y",what does "yields" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Like what I say in the title,what does yield mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this, where you wonder what a word means, I advise using a dictionary, many of which are available online.  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yield) has a definition of yield:

> to produce or furnish as return
>
> Example: *this soil should **yield** good crops*

So in your case, it basically means, "bring about," or "produce."

> It **produces** accurate predictions...